# How quickly does sugar cane grow?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently started a sugar cane farm, and I'm just curious as to the rate at which sugar cane grows.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have an automatic piston-harvested farm with 16 cane plants harvested every ~10 seconds. Here are two different estimations of the rate. By "growth" I mean the event of one block being added to the top of a sugar cane plant.

- When I watch the farm running, it seems to drop about 1 cane every 2 cycles (but this is a fuzzy memory); this would be a rate of (1 cane)/(20 seconds)/(16 plants) = **1/320 growths per plant per second**.
- When I come by to collect its drops, I usually get 6-8 canes (but this excludes the number which miss the water stream and get stuck inside the farm); if the farm has been active and the collection point untouched for a full 5 minutes = 300 seconds (item despawn time), then we get (8 canes)/(300 seconds)/(16 plants) = **1/600 growths per plant per second**.

The latter figure is probably closer to correct as it does not involve an estimation of probability.

Comment: So between 5 to 10 minutes?

Comment: Yes, but recognize that that's for *one* plant.

Comment: Dang, are you trying to *corner* the Sugar market? What do you need all that sugar cane for, anyway? :)

Comment: The occasional bookcase or cake? — The thing here is that this is running all the time, and I've arranged so that I run over the drops whenever I arrive at my base from a railway. Thus I gather materials without needing to take any action. At that amount of inattention, this much cane collection is just right. — Also, if you think this is too much, you [haven't seen my cactus farm](http://imgur.com/a/KlDDx) (which goes into the same collection system). If you like, check it out on my server at `mc.switchb.org`!

Comment: Also, sugar cane grows faster when planted on sand than on regular dirt or grass.

Answer (score 15):

Sugar cane grows using block ticks. Every 16 block ticks it grows, and each block tick happens on average every 68 seconds, that means on average a sugar cane will grow every 1088 seconds, or 18 minutes 8 seconds. This is only with optimal conditions however. Watch all of Wubbi's video, it's really helpful and accurate.

Sources:

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tick

Comment: Welcome to Arqade.  This is a great post.  Keep them coming.  Also, please take the time to read the tour under the help tab.  It can be very helpful in understanding the site's protocols for Q&A.

Answer (score -1):

Mine grow by one block every 18 mins. I have harvested about 600 sugar cane last week so I'M the one cornering the sugar market.

Answer (score -3):

It takes exacally 20.3 seconds for it to grow. However, if  you do not have water around it, it takes 50.80 seconds! ○:

Comment: There is no exact time. It's random. Water is also irrelevant to growth rate.